# How to centre two different layers without losing position - After Effects

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, creative-cloud, adobe-creative-suite

In Photoshop or Illustrator you can select two different layers, group them, and then when you align them to the centre they keep their original layout, but are now equally spaced left/right. Is there no options to do this in After Effects?? When I select two layers and press the "centre" align button it just overlaps the two layers in the centre rather than keeping the original layout.

Any way to get around having to just "eyeball it"???

Comment: You can do this by making a `Layer > New > Null Object`, set it as the parent for the two layers and then align (or animate) the null. Alternatively, you can Precomp the layers and align the comp. The latter method is very close to using a Smart Object in Photoshop.

Comment: @Joonas - shouldn't that be an answer?